# R - make multiple elements list to data frame rows

Tags: r, list

I have a data frame like below.

```
    A  B C
V1  a  1 e
V2  b  2 f
V3  c  3 g,h,i
V4  d  4 j,k
```

Class of data in C column is list.

And I want to unlist the C column data and make multiple rows in data frame like this.

```
    A  B C
V1  a  1 e
V2  b  2 f
V3  c  3 g
V4  c  3 h
V5  c  3 i
V6  d  4 j
V7  d  4 k
```

How to do this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `cSplit`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df1, "C", sep=",", "long")
#   A B C
#1: a 1 e
#2: b 2 f
#3: c 3 g
#4: c 3 h
#5: c 3 i
#6: d 4 j
#7: d 4 k
```

Or use `unnest` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
unnest(df1, C=strsplit(C, ","))
#  A B C
#1 a 1 e
#2 b 2 f
#3 c 3 g
#4 c 3 h
#5 c 3 i
#6 d 4 j
#7 d 4 k
```

Or with `base R`

```
lst <- strsplit(df1$C, ",")
transform(df1[rep(1:nrow(df1), lengths(lst)),-3], C= unlist(lst))
#     A B C
#V1   a 1 e
#V2   b 2 f
#V3   c 3 g
#V3.1 c 3 h
#V3.2 c 3 i
#V4   d 4 j
#V4.1 d 4 k
```

NOTE: If the "C" column is `factor`, convert to `character` and use it in `strsplit` i.e. `strsplit(as.character(df1$C), ",")`

#### Update

Suppose if the column "C" is a `list`, we can still use `unnest`

```
unnest(df2, C)
#  A B C
#1 a 1 e
#2 b 2 f
#3 c 3 g
#4 c 3 h
#5 c 3 i
#6 d 4 j
#7 d 4 k
```

Or with `listCol_l` from `splitstackshape`

```
listCol_l(df2, "C")[]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), B = 1:4, C = c("e", 
"f", "g,h,i", "j,k")), .Names = c("A", "B", "C"), 
class = "data.frame",   row.names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"))

df2 <- structure(list(A = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), B = 1:4, C = list("e", 
"f", c("g", "h", "i"), c("j", "k"))), .Names = c("A", "B", 
"C"), row.names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks. But the result is c('g' 'h' 'i') spread in three rows. I want to just g h i on each row, not in c( )

Comment: @LuisKang  I am getting the expected result as you showed

Comment: unnest(df2, C) this code works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
s <- strsplit(df$C, split = ",")
data.frame(A = rep(df$A, sapply(s, length)), C = unlist(s))
```

Comment: this looses the `B` column ....

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus Since col A & B are always same(in the question) I think they may just add the missing column later.